# Find two non isomorphic galois extensions of degree three of $Q(z_6)$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

As it is in the title, I am looking for two Galois extensions of degree 3 of $Q(z_6)$ where $z_6$ is the primitive 6th root of unity.

My idea: Take $Q(z_6,\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $Q(z_6,\sqrt[3]{3})$ These are extensions of degree 3 from $Q(z_6)$ and are splitting fields of $(x^2-x+1)(x^3-2)$ and $(x^2-x+1)(x^3-2)$ over $Q$ so they are Galois. Thus by FT of Galois, $Q(z_6,\sqrt[3]{2})/Q(z_6)$ is Galois. Hence, the only problem is to show these two are not isomorphic which i do not know how to do. My idea would be to show there is not thing in $Q(z_6,\sqrt[3]{3})$ that if you $^3$ you get $2$. But showing that form a basis is an impossible task. Is there a shorter way? Perhaps these are isomorphic? Are two extensions isomorphic iff they are roots of the same polynomial?

Thank you

Comment: These are Kummer extensions of $K=\Bbb Q(z_6)$. To show they are different, you need to show that neither $2\cdot3$ nor $2\cdot3^2$ are cubes in $K$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am not sure what those are, and it seems like an overkill, is there a simpler, perhaps more direct solution? I was never taught Kummer extensions

Comment: Like it or not, these are examples of Kummer extensions, and you can read the basics here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer_theory To solve this problem from scratch, you must inevitably reconstruct a small part of this theory.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little strange to take a sixth root of unity $z_6 = \zeta_6$, since $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_6) = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3) = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-3})$.

As to the answer, of course @lord-shark-the-unknown is correct, but here is an elementary solution that uses neither Kummer theory nor anything about ramification.

Let's take the following two fields:

$$L = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_{9}), \qquad K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3,\sqrt[3]{2}).$$

Using material in a standard course on Galois theory, one has

$$\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf{Q}) = (\mathbf{Z}/9 \mathbf{Z})^{\times} \simeq \mathbf{Z}/6 \mathbf{Z},$$
$$\mathrm{Gal}(K/\mathbf{Q}) \simeq S_3,$$

Certainly both $L$ and $K$ contain $E$, and so $E$ is the field corresponding to the unique surjections  onto $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ in either case. Galois theory again tells you that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/E) = \mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z} \subset \mathbf{Z}/6 \mathbf{Z}$ and $\mathrm{Gal}(K/E) =  \mathbf{Z}/3 \mathbf{Z} \subset S_3$, so these are both Galois extensions of $E$ of degree $3$. On the other hand, clearly $K$ and $L$ are not isomorphic fields because they have different Galois groups over $\mathbf{Q}$.

.